# Partitioning $\mathbb Q^+_0$ in 2-element sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers, set-partition

I'm having trouble solving the following exercise:

> Find a partitioning of the set $\{x\in \mathbb Q | x \geq 0\}$ in disjoint subsets, each containing two elements.

Now at first I thought about pairs $(a,b) := \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ whith whom you could identify $\frac{a}{b}$, but they are rather subsets of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, right? Maybe there is an easy solution, but neither I nor my friends couldn't come up with one yet.

Comment: HINT: Find a way of pairing elements. Don't get bogged down with symbols whether you will be able to express it in symbols and such extraneous concerns. Think about numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $\frac pq$ is a rational number such that $p$ and $q$ are positive integers and coprime, then $\frac qp\neq\frac pq$ as long as $p\neq q$.

This will leave you with exactly two numbers in your set which cannot be represented like that.

Formally, as requested by the OP in the comments, this would be, $$\{0,1\}\cup\left\{\left\{\frac pq,\frac qp\right\}\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}\begin{array}{l}p,q\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\},\\ \gcd(p,q)=1,\\ p\neq q\end{array}\right\}$$

Of course, if you define $\Bbb N$ as starting with $1$, you don't have to add that $\setminus\{0\}$ part.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got the idea :)

Comment: Would the following family of sets satisfy everything? $$M_i = \{\frac{a_i}{b_i}, \frac{b_i}{a_i} : a_i \in \mathbb N_0, b_i \in \mathbb N, a_i \neq b_i, ggT(a_i, b_i) = 1\} \cup \{0,1\}$$

Comment: Well, it's not clear it's a set of sets, but the general idea is right. You might want to write gcd and not ggT, by the way.

Comment: Nice; calls to mind the Stern-Brocot tree, though that has far more structure than is needed here.

Comment: Oh, of course it should be gcd. I confused it with the German term. Thanks!

Comment: Could you maybe give me the correct formal way of writing down the set I want to express?

Comment: @lappen68: There you go.

Answer (score 3):

You know that the (nonnegative) rationals are countable, so let $f$ be your favorite bijection to the natural numbers. It's easy to partition the range as required:   use the pairs consisting of an even number and the next odd one.

This is less constructive and less elegant than @AsafKaragila 's nice trick - but it works for any countable set.

Comment: Pretty elegant way of proving it. Is the following implementation correct? Let $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$ bijective. Define $M_i = \{f(2i), f(2i+1)\}$ for all $i \in \mathbb N_0$. Then $M_i \cap M_j = \emptyset$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb N_0$ and $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N_0} M_i = \mathbb Q$. Or do I explicitly have to specify the function $f$?

Comment: @lappen68 If I were your teacher I wouldn't expect you to specify $f$. I wouldn't even need the formal argument in your comment - I'd accept my prose answer. But it's good to be able to make that argument, which is nicest the way you did it, with a map from to the rationals rather than from the rationals.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For $0\ne x\ne 1$ let $F(x)=\{x,1/x\} .$ Let $F(0)=F(1)=\{0,1\}.$ Let $G=\{F(x): 0\leq x \in \mathbb Q\}.$